# Scrapyd only - No module name django_project.settings

Tags: python, django, scrapy, django-settings, scrapyd

This error only happens on the command `scrapyd-deploy`.

```
Packing version r240-master
Deploying to project "foo_bot" in http://localhost:6802/addversion.json
Server response (200):

{
    "status": "error", 
    "message": "Traceback (most recent call last):
      File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
        \"__main__\", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd/runner.py\", line 40, in <module>
        main()
      File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd/runner.py\", line 37, in main
        execute()
      File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py\", line 109, in execute
        settings = get_project_settings()
      File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py\", line 68, in get_project_settings
        settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
      File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py\", line 292, in setmodule
        module = import_module(module)
      File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py\", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File \"build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/foo_bot/settings.py\", line 21, in <module>
      File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py\", line 22, in setup
        configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
      File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py\", line 56, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py\", line 41, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py\", line 110, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py\", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
        ImportError: No module named foo_project.settings
    ", 
    "node_name": "ubuntu"
}
```

The project structure is as follow:

```
/home/dev/workspace/fufu
|--dev_venv/bin/activate
|
|--foo_bot
|  |--scrapy.cfg
|  |
|  |--foo_bot
|     |--settings.py
|     |--settings_dev.py
|     |--settings_deploy.py
|     |--items.py and blablabla
|     |--spiders
|        |--blablablaspider.py
|
|--foo_project
   |--manage.py
   |
   |--app
   |  |--models.py and blablabla
   |
   |--foo_project
      |--settings.py
      |--settings_dev.py
      |--settings_deploy.py
      |--wsgi.py and blablabla
```

`scrapy.cfg`

```
[settings]
default = foo_bot.settings

[deploy:local]
url = http://localhost:6801/
project = foo_bot

[deploy:development]
url = http://localhost:6802/
project = foo_bot
version = GIT

[deploy:deployment]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = foo_bot
version = GIT
```

`foo_bot/foo_bot/settings.py`

```
import os
import sys
import django

########## PATH CONFIGURATION
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
FALSE_BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
#WORKSPACE_DIR = os.path.dirname(FALSE_BASE_DIR) // fail with just scrapy crawl bar
WORKSPACE_DIR = '/'.join([os.path.expanduser('~'), 'workspace'])
BOT_NAME = 'foo_bot'
########## END PATH CONFIGURATION

########## DJANGO CONFIGURATION
DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH = '/'.join([FALSE_BASE_DIR, 'foo_project'])
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'foo_project.settings'
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH)
sys.path.insert(0, DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
django.setup()
########## END DJANGO CONFIGURATION

#blablabla settings

try:
    from settings_dev import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

`foo_project/foo_project/settings.py`

```
import os

########## PATH CONFIGURATION
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
FALSE_BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
WORKSPACE_DIR = os.path.dirname(FALSE_BASE_DIR)
PROJECT_NAME = 'foo_project'
########## END PATH CONFIGURATION
```

`foo_project/foo_project/wsgi.py`

```
import os

from django import conf
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

conf.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'foo_project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And I use `virtualenv` to set the environment variables `PYTHONPATH` and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` at the end of `activate` script as follow:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/dev/workspace/fufu/foo_project"
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="foo_project.settings"
```

I run `scrapy crawl bar` at `fufu/foo_bot`, it runs successfully (and save to database through `djangoitem`).

I run `django-admin.py` at `fufu/foo_project`, it runs successfully with no warnings.

I run `python manage.py` at `fufu/foo_project`, it runs successfully with no warings.

I run `scrapyd-deploy development -p foo_bot` with user `dev` and virutalenv `dev_venv`.

It returns errors as the above.

The `scrapyd` is called at `/home/dev/workspace/` with user `dev` and port `6802`

> However, I have another user `deploy` with a project copy at `/home/deploy/workspace/fufu/` with only different on the `from settings_dev` to `from settings_deploy` and those absolute paths.
>
> I run `scrapyd-deploy deployment -p foo_bot` with user `deploy` and virutalenv `deploy_venv`.
>
> It runs perfectly.
>
> The `scrapyd` is called at `/home/deploy/workspace/` with user `deploy` and port `6800`.

How can I solve this? I have seen all the threads and I have no idea why `dev` user fails but `deploy` user works.

Comment: Shouldn't `foo_project.settings` be `foo_project.foo_bot.settings`?

Comment: That's my typo when I typed the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it.
It is because of `os.path.dirname()` will get me empty path.

`foo_bot/foo_bot/settings.py`

```
########## PATH CONFIGURATION
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
#FALSE_BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
#WORKSPACE_DIR = os.path.dirname(FALSE_BASE_DIR) // fail with just scrapy crawl bar
WORKSPACE_DIR = '/'.join([os.path.expanduser('~'), 'workspace'])
FALSE_BASE_DIR = '/'.join([WORKSPACE_DIR, 'fufu'])
BOT_NAME = 'foo_bot'
########## END PATH CONFIGURATION
```